# Capybara click is lost on div surrounding input node

Tags: capybara, ruby-on-rails-4.2, capybara-webkit

I am using Rails 4.2, Capybara 2.5, and Poltergeist 1.8. I have an input tag inside a `div` whose id is `#foobar`, and in my JS, I have a click event handler for `#foobar`.

`<div id='foobar'><input type=submit></div>
 <script>$('#foobar').click(function() {})</script>`

Everything works as expected in a browser but my tests fail if I send a Capybara click to the div instead of the input tag:

*Test works*

`page.find('#foobar input').click`

*Test does not work*

`page.find('#foobar').click`

Is this a known problem, or am I understanding the expected behavior incorrectly?

Comment: This should work, assuming you don't have any other click handlers interfering with the click.   Are you seeing this with both capybara-webkit and poltergeist drivers? (youve tagged with both) Do you also see the behavior when you use selenium?

Comment: Now I can't repro consistently :( I did mistakenly add poltergeist, so it's just webkit. When I switch to Selenium it worked, then worked back with webkit, then stopped working... I need to turn this into a couple of branches to do it more thoroughly.